# Handle Redis requirement in project a bit more elegant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, redis

Im using redis in on of my projects and have a initialiser with redis = Redis.new and using the redis gem. Problem is that if Redis is not running I cannot do anything like a simple database migration.

Is there a more elegant way to handle using redis so that my application throws an error instead of just not working when redis is not running?

Im using process monitoring to keep redis running correctly and monitor its memory/cpu but still if it does not run all things break and look for a more elegant way. if possible

EDit:

This is my initialiser

```
$redis = Redis.new

heartbeat_thread = Thread.new do
  while true
    $redis.publish("heartbeat","thump")
    sleep 30.seconds
  end
end

at_exit do
  # not sure this is needed, but just in case
  heartbeat_thread.kill
  $redis.quit
end
```

Comment: I have never worked with Ruby client. but ideally if redis is not running you should get timeout error which you can handle at application level.

Comment: Configure the redis gem such that it handles connect/reconnect logic behind the scenes; you should not be doing that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you create a connection to redis before doing any request ?

It seems that you dont need that and I suggest you do connect to redis only when you actually have to send some request to it.

I am not very familiar with redis ruby client but I am pretty sure you can achieve this easily.

Comment: Connecting to redis everytime you fire a command? That will be big decrease in performance. Connecting time + Everytime it will select database. So eventually for every command you will be firing two commands + connection time.

Comment: @Atul my suggestion is to open the connection the first time its needed and then keep it, not to create a new connection every time.

Comment: Im using Rails SSE to have a constant connection with the client. I look into perhaps only enable this when a user logs in since before it would not be needed.

Comment: I have this code in the updated edited version in an initialiser, Guess I could move that towards a custom method that is called when user logsin.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli: Cool then !!! :) Rubytastic: I am not sure i understand the question properly. How it will solve the problem when you enable Redis connection when user logs in? What if Redis is not running at the time of User logs in? Wouldn't you be back to square?

Comment: @Rubytastic keep in mind that the connection between rails and redis can get closed (redis connection timeout, network issues, redis restart...) your app should be able to deal with that